# IE losing iframe contents after back/forward key

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, iframe, back

This problem is only happening in IE (at least 8 and 9).  After an element is dynamically added to the DOM, the contents of an embedded iframe are lost when the page is reentered with a BACK/FORWARD key.  Just two small HTML files will reproduce the issue.

The first file is iframe.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IE iframe bug</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mytrace(msg) {
            var t = document.createTextNode(msg);
            var b = document.createElement('br');
            var d = document.getElementById("trace_output")
            d.appendChild(t);
            d.appendChild(b); /// will work if commented
        }
        function submitListing() {
            mytrace('submitListing()');
            var doc = document.getElementById("output_iframe")
                .contentWindow.document;
            var d = new Date;
            doc.location.replace('report.htm?invalidateCache=' + d.getTime());
            //mytrace('submitListing(): out');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="trace_output"><br /></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="submitListing();" value="Run" /><br />
    <iframe id="output_iframe" src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The second file is report.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_top">LINK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps to recreate the issue (BACK KEY)

1. Place above content in two files
2. Browse the iframe.htm file
3. Press the Run button to load report.htm in the iframe
4. Click on the LINK link to load a different page
5. Press the browser BACK button to returned to the "cached" (lmao) page
6. iframe contents are gone!!!! (only in IE-- safari, chrome, firefox retain the contents)

Also..(FORWARD KEY)

1. Browse to an arbitrary page (for history, http://www.google.com works)
2. Load iframe.htm into the same tab
3. Press the Run button to load report.htm in the iframe
4. Press the browser BACK button to return to the first page
5. Press the browser FORWARD button to return to iframe.htm
6. iframe contents are gone again!!

Now comment out the line:

```
d.appendChild(b)
```

That one change allows everything to work in IE.  However, my solution needs to make those kinds of DOM manipulations (heavy jQuery/AJAX app) AND be able to restore the iframe across browser BACK/FORWARD actions.

It seems that I will have to remember the contents of the iframe so that I can restore it when the page is accessed with the BACK/FORWARD keys.  I'm not thrilled with this because sometimes the iframe content will be quite large and it could chew up a bit of memory and time to make another copy of the embedded document for the restore.  I would love to hear some other ideas about how I could approach this.  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The following replacement to iframe.htm will work around the problem with IE.  I'm going to rewrite this using jQuery and add some more logic to restore the scroll positions.  I had hoped for something more elegant, but this is doing the job.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IE iframe bug</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myTrace(msg) {
            var t = document.createTextNode(msg);
            var b = document.createElement('br');
            var d = document.getElementById("trace_output")
            d.appendChild(t);
            d.appendChild(b); 
        }
        var make_backup ="false";
        function submitListing() {
            make_backup = "true";
            myTrace('submitListing()');
            var doc = document.getElementById("output_iframe").contentWindow.document;
            var d = new Date;
            doc.location.replace('report.htm?invalidateCache=' + d.getTime());
            //myTrace('submitListing(): out');
        }
        function iframe_load() {
            myTrace("iframe loaded, is_cached=" + document.getElementById("is_cached").value);
            if (make_backup == "true") { // only when submitting
                var htm, doc;
                make_backup = "false"
                doc = document.getElementById("output_iframe").contentWindow.document;
                htm = doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("iframe_backup").value = htmlEscape(htm);
            }
        }
        function bodyLoaded() {
            var is_cached = document.getElementById("is_cached");
            if (is_cached.value == "false") {  // initial page load 
                is_cached.value = "true";
            }
            else { // BACK or FORWARD,  restore DOM where needed 
                var htm;
                htm = htmlUnescape(document.getElementById("iframe_backup").value);
                var doc;
                doc = document.getElementById("output_iframe").contentWindow.document;
                doc.open();
                doc.writeln(htm);
                doc.close();
            }
        }
        function htmlEscape(str) {
            return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        }
        function htmlUnescape(str) {
            return String(str).replace(/&amp;/g,'&').replace(/&quot;/g,'"')
            .replace(/&#39;/g,"'").replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyLoaded();">
    <div id="trace_output" style="height: 300px; border-width:1; background-color: Silver"><br></div>
    <input id="is_cached" type="hidden" value="false">
    <input id="iframe_backup" type="hidden">
    <input type="button" onclick="submitListing();" value="Run"><br>
    <iframe id="output_iframe" src="" onload="iframe_load();"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

Rewritten with jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IE iframe workaround2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var make_backup = "false";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            myTrace('document ready()');
            var is_cached = $("#is_cached");
            if (is_cached.val() == "false") {  // initial page load 
                is_cached.val("true");
            }
            else { // BACK or FORWARD,  restore DOM where needed 
                if ($.browser.msie) { // IE loses iframe content; restore 
                    var htm = htmlUnescape($("#iframe_backup").val());
                    var doc = $("#output_iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
                    doc.open();
                    doc.writeln(htm);
                    doc.close();
                    myTrace('iframe contents restored');
                }
            }
            $('#output_iframe').load(function () {
                myTrace("iframe_loaded");
                if (make_backup == "true") { // only when submitting
                    make_backup = "false"
                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        var doc = $("#output_iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
                        var htm = doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
                        $("#iframe_backup").val(htmlEscape(htm));
                        myTrace('iframe contents backed up');
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#submit_listing').click(function () {
                make_backup = "true";
                myTrace('submitListing()');
                var doc = $("#output_iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
                var d = new Date;
                doc.location.replace('report.htm?invalidateCache='+d.getTime());
            });
        });
        function myTrace(msg) {
            $('#trace_output').append(msg + '<br>'); 
        }
        function htmlEscape(str) {
            return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        }
        function htmlUnescape(str) {
            return String(str).replace(/&amp;/g,'&').replace(/&quot;/g,'"')
            .replace(/&#39;/g,"'").replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="trace_output" 
         style="height: 300px; border-width:1; background-color: Silver">
         <br></div>
    <div style="display: block;">
        <input id="is_cached" type="text" value="false">
        <input id="iframe_backup" type="text" type="hidden"></div>
    <input id="submit_listing" type="button" value="Run"><br>
    <iframe id="output_iframe" src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an off-topic note: self-closing tags are not really correct in HTML5 documents.  They *usually* don't hurt anything, but that's because of error-correcting behavior. It's better not to do it. Tags like `<input>` and `<br>` need no closing tag.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Pointy.  VS2010 has been replacing my > with  /> for input and br tags.  I'll have to see how to turn that off.  :)

Comment: Client-side coding tools written by server-side programmers :rolleyes: :-)